# max() and min() python

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, min

I'm having a simple trouble but I don't know how to solve it.

This is my code, so far:

```
class CorRGB:

    def __init__(self, red, green, blue):
        self.r = min(1.0,red);
        self.g = min(1.0,green);
        self.b = min(1.0,blue);


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.r*255) + str(" ") + str(self.g) + str(" ") + str(self.b)


c1 = CorRGB(10.0, -4.0, 0.1)
print(str(c1))
```

So, if the r,g,b values are greater than 1.0, it has to return 1.0. And if the r,g,b values are lower than 0.0 it has to return 0.0. I have to use the `min()` and `max()` functions, but I can only work with one at a time, I need to use them both for the same argument.

Comment: ... `min(1.0, max(color, 0.0))`?

Comment: thanks!!! i feel so dumb xD

Comment: why you have to use min() and max()? cant you just use an inline if statement like `self.red = red if 0 < red < 1.0 else 1.0`

Comment: @DSLima90 I think your statement is wrong for negative numbers, which get mapped to 1.0 instead of 0.0.

Comment: @ChristianKönig, you are right! I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common idiom in this case is to pass the result of one function as the argument of the other:

```
self.r = min(max(red, 0.0), 1.0)
```

This is roughly equivalent to something like

```
temp = max(red, 0.0)
self.r = min(temp, 1.0)
```

It does not matter what order you call `max` and `min` in in this case. So the following would work fine too:

```
self.r = max(min(red, 1.0), 0.0)
```